# C# text from textbox to string array

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to add text from textbox to string[] array by pressing button3 i value will add to new array and clear textbox.

Button1 is to go up on array and Button2 is for go down.

I make this but it wont work:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int arr1 = 0;
        public int arr2 = 0;
        public string[] array = new string[100];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (arr1 < array.Length - 1)
            {
                if (array[arr1] != "")
                {
                    arr1++;
                    textBox1.Text = array[arr1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                arr1 = 0;
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (arr1 < array.Length - 1)
            {
                if (array[arr1] != "")
                {
                    arr1--;
                    textBox1.Text = array[arr1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                arr1 = 0;
            }
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            array[arr1] = textBox1.Text;
            listBox1.Items.Add(array[arr1]);
            arr2++;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: What does "wont work:" mean?

Comment: what does `arr2` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `arr2++` by `arr1++` as following

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        array[arr1] = textBox1.Text;
        listBox1.Items.Add(array[arr1]);
        arr1++;
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```